# Remove array element according to the chosen item from the list

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I have a list of incomes each with its own value and its own delete icon.
When adding an income to the list, an array is filled with its values and then sum those values.

The idea is that at the time of deleting an item from the list, it will also be deleted from the array.

```js
const txtDescripIncome = document.getElementById("descriptionIncome");
const txtIncomeValue = document.getElementById("incomeValue");
const btnAdd = document.getElementById("addIncome");
const span = document.getElementById("total-money");
const spanList = document.getElementsByClassName('badge badge-primary badge-pill');
let j;
let arrayValueIncomes = [];
deleteArray = [];

//**************************************************************************************************************************************** */
                                                            //FUNCTIONS
//****************************************************************************************************************************************

//***************add income to list********************
function addIncome() {
  let descriIncome = txtDescripIncome.value;
  let IncomeValue = txtIncomeValue.value;
  let listItem = document.createElement("li");
  let i;

  listItem.className =
    "list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center";
  listItem.innerHTML = `${descriIncome} <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">$ ${IncomeValue}</span>  <a href="#" class="delete-income" ><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>`;

  document.getElementById("listIncomes").appendChild(listItem);
  sumIncomes();
  txtDescripIncome.value = "";
  txtIncomeValue.value = "";

  for(let i = 0; i<spanList.length; i++){
    spanList[i].setAttribute("data-id", i)
    console.log(spanList.item(i).innerHTML)
  }

  //***************Delete income from the list********************
  function deleteIncome() {
    const list = document.querySelectorAll(".list-group-item");
    let tab = [],
      liIndex;

    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      tab.push(list[i].innerHTML);
      //console.log(tab);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      list[i].onclick = function() {
        liIndex = tab.indexOf(this.innerHTML);
        //console.log(this.innerHTML + "INDEX = " + liIndex);
        deleting();
        list[liIndex].parentNode.removeChild(list[liIndex]);
      };
    }
  }

  deleteIncome();
}

function deleteIncomeFromArray() {}

//***********Sum all Incomes************************
function sumIncomes() {
  let item = txtIncomeValue.value;
  arrayValueIncomes.push(parseInt(item));
  let sum = arrayValueIncomes.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  span.innerHTML = sum;
}

function deleting() {
  arrayValueIncomes.forEach(function (currentValue, index, array) {
    let x = currentValue
    //let nodo = spanList.item(x).dataset.id
    let i = arrayValueIncomes.indexOf(x)
    console.log(i)
    arrayValueIncomes.splice(i, 1)
  })
  console.log(arrayValueIncomes)
}


  
  
 

 

//**************************************************************************************************************************************** */
//EVENT LISTENERS
//****************************************************************************************************************************************
btnAdd.addEventListener("click", addIncome);
```

```css
/* ******************************************************************************************************************************************
                                                        CARD STYLES
 *******************************************************************************************************************************************/
.title-income{
    text-align: center;
}

.card{
    margin-top:30px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23); 
}

.income-list{
    margin-top:15px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-SI27wrMjH3ZZ89r4o+fGIJtnzkAnFs3E4qz9DIYioCQ5l9Rd/7UAa8DHcaL8jkWt" crossorigin="anonymous">
    

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>


  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">


      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">

          <div class="card" style="width: 33rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class= section-income>
                <div class= title-income>
                  <h2>Month Incomes</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="incomes">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Income Description" id="descriptionIncome">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Income Value" id="incomeValue">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="addIncome">Add</button>
                </div>
                <div class="income-list">
                  <ul class="list-group" id="listIncomes">

                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class = total-income>
                  <span id = "total-money" class = total>0</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>





























    </div>














    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-3qaqj0lc6sV/qpzrc1N5DC6i1VRn/HyX4qdPaiEFbn54VjQBEU341pvjz7Dv3n6P" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
   
  </body>
</html>
```

For some reason the delete icon is not shown in this editor.

In the previous code it does not work correctly since at the time of removing an item, 2 or more items are removed from the array and not the specific item selected.

Comment: In a glance, instead of using tab array to capture innerHtml, use it it hold  dom element as such which will solve the issue.
`tab.push(list[i]); instead of tab.push(list[i].innerHTML);
if (tab.indexOf(this) > -1)
  this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
instead of 
   list[liIndex].parentNode.removeChild(list[liIndex]);`

Comment: thank you for the answer. but the problem is not on the rows of the app. the problem is at the moment to delete a income from the list for example $100, this value is not erase. you can check it on the console.log

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your implementation below code exactly does what is it supposed to be.. replace the below script block on your code.

```
<script>

const txtDescripIncome = document.getElementById("descriptionIncome");
const txtIncomeValue = document.getElementById("incomeValue");
const btnAdd = document.getElementById("addIncome");
const span = document.getElementById("total-money");
const spanList = document.getElementsByClassName('badge badge-primary badge-pill');
let j;
let arrayValueIncomes = [];
let total = 0;
deleteArray = [];

function addIncome() {
  let descriIncome = txtDescripIncome.value;
  let IncomeValue = txtIncomeValue.value;
  let listItem = document.createElement("li");
  let i;

  listItem.className = "list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center";
  listItem.innerHTML = `${descriIncome} <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">$ ${IncomeValue}</span>  <a href="#" class="delete-income" ><i class="far fa-trash-alt">Del</i></a>`;

  document.getElementById("listIncomes").appendChild(listItem);

  txtDescripIncome.value = "";
  txtIncomeValue.value = "";
  listItem.dataset.data = parseFloat(IncomeValue);
  total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(listItem.dataset.data);
  listItem.onclick = function() {
    total = total - this.dataset.data;
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    span.innerHTML = total;
    console.log(total);
  };
  console.log(total);
  span.innerHTML = total;
}

btnAdd.addEventListener("click", addIncome);

</script>
```